# Why does the memory usage shown by psutil differ so much from what cgroups shows?

Tags: python, kubernetes, memory, psutil, cgroups

While running a Python service in Kubernetes (pod with just one container, my Gunicorn process has PID `1`), I monitor the memory usage:

```py
psutil.Process().memory_full_info()
```

output:

```
pfullmem(rss=669609984, vms=5986619392, shared=229244928, text=4096, lib=0, data=3318370304, dirty=0, uss=658903040, pss=664651776, swap=0)
```

However, `cgroups` (which Kubernetes uses to decide when to OOM-kill a pod)

```bash
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.current
```

shows (at the same time):

```
474193920
```

So it does not correspond to any of the values shown by `psutil`.

Where the difference comes from?

Comment: This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212787/how-to-correctly-report-available-ram-within-a-docker-container#:~:text=Docker%20uses%20CGroups%20to%20control%20resource%20usage%20by,%2Fproc%2Fmeminfo%20file%20which%20shows%20system%27s%2C%20not%20container%2C%20capabilities.